# Distribution of charges: parallel plates and potential

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, capacitance

How do you calculate the charge distribution on three parallel plates which have unequal charges on them and then they are connected by a wire?

Also, we need to calculate the field and potential after the redistribution of charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can equate the potentials of the plates that are connected by a wire. And secondly, since the plates are conducting, the net electric field at any point inside any of the plate will be zero.

Also, if the plates are given to be very large/infinite, you can assume that two plates together form a conductor, because if they’re very large they can be assumed to be meeting at infinity. And if that’s the case, the fact that the net charge inside of a conductor is zero will also help.

Comment: can you be more detailed?